# How I can avoid that a EC2 instance be turns on by itself

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I am having a problem with a EC2 instance, no matter how many times I turn off it, turns on by itself. ¿Anyone knows how i can turn off definitely?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is probably caused by the fact the that instance is running in [EC2 Auto Scaling](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/autoscaling/ec2/userguide/what-is-amazon-ec2-auto-scaling.html).

You can verify if you have any autoscaling groups (ASG) using EC2 console, on the bottom of its main menu:

[image]

If your instance is running as part of an ASG, the ASG will be re-launching it when you terminate it. Thus, to rectify the issue you can remove the ASG along with the instance, or just detach your instance from it.

[image]

Comment: You were right the instance was tied to an auto-scaling group I already deleted it, Thank you so much.